# Requests are well below Google Calendar quotas yet we still get some 403 responses

Tags: google-calendar-api

We occasionally get this error back when trying to POST to the `/events` endpoint.

```
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "quotaExceeded",
      "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
  }
}
```

However, we seem to be well below our quota. Our quota is 20,000 requests per minute, and our seven-day peak is under 12,000. Yet these errors persist. (Our quota for requests per user per minute is 60,000,000 which doesn't make any sense.)

We have one user who is creating a large number of events (26,000 over the last 30 days) and that user gets the bulk of these messages, but other users get them, too...users that we've confirmed are *well* below these kinds of limits.

We found [this workspace administrator help document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486) that indicates some types of Workspace accounts (new, cheap, etc.) might have tighter restrictions. Do those restrictions apply if somebody is Oauthing in to our project to use the Google Calendar API?

Comment: I believe the best way for you to get help is to contact the [Google Workspace developer support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110).